# ¿Cómo obtener el código HTML crudo de una página en HTMLUnit?

Tags: java

Necesito obtener el código HTML tal cual lo envía el servidor. Note que el método `asXml()` devuelve algo similar pero está formateado.

¿Hay alguna forma de resolver esto usando esta librería o tengo que recurrir a llamadas de bajo nivel?

Comment: Para futuras referencias, si conoces la respuesta ([como es el caso](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10092554) ;P) no hay ningún problema en que seas tú el que crea y conteste la misma pregunta, de hecho [está aceptado](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) por las normas de la comunidad.

Comment: Claro! Pero la idea es agregar preguntas a esta beta asi la gente se motiva. Si agrego la repuesta ya otros van a perder el interes en responderla. Esta fue la pregunta 37... hay muy poco para elegir

Comment: Hmmmm... ¿Crees entonces que debería quitar la mía? Al fin y al cabo no aporta nada nuevo, jejeje.

Comment: Nah, esta perfecto. Veamos si alguno conoce algun mecanismo mas reciente que resuelva el problema (ya hace unos años que respondi esa pregunta)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que lo más próximo a lo que estás buscando es:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.setAppletEnabled(false);
webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

Para HtmlUnit 2.13 y superior, usa `webclient.getOptions()`.

También puede que te resulte interesante [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200886/extremely-simple-code-not-working-in-htmlunit-2-9-stable) pregunta.

Finalmente, para conseguir el contenido original de la página (en vez de la salida de `asXml()`) prueba lo siguiente:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.tupagina.com");
String originalHtml = page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
```

*(Traducido de [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10091359) pregunta de StackOverflow en inglés)*